Docker is not creating database with the parallel_test gem
this is my database.yml file
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: UTF-8
  host: localhost
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 10 } %>

test:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['TEST_DATABASE_URL'] %>
  database: testing<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %> # do not change this value!!!
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 20 } %>
  encoding: UTF-8

development:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %> 
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 20 } %>
  encoding: UTF-8

ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] is not fetched in docker compose , and it is working fine on my local but not in docker , any suggestions

Is ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] actually set on your test environment? Try using ENV.fetch("TEST_ENV_NUMBER") instead, then Ruby raises an error when the ENV is not set.

the issue is on docker i cant create multiple databases for multiple processes. On local these both are working fine

Sure, but that doesn't answer if and how ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] set on docker.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In order to create the databases for parallel_tests you need to invoke the parallel:create task before running the tests. In a docker-compose setup with RSpec I would suggest running the following command
command: [
      "sh", "-c", "bundle exec rake parallel:create parallel:load_schema && bundle exec parallel_rspec spec/"
    ]

